# Insert record with AJAX not inserting and refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im trying to update my DB using AJAX and PHP. I'm sure everything is right only my page refreshes and nothings inserted into my table.

***HTML***

```
<form id="salary-upd">
      <input type="text" class="defaultText" id="monthly-income" name="monthly-income" title="What is your salary?">
      <input type="submit" class="salary-upd-submit">
</form>
<div></div>
```

***AJAX***

```
// UPDATE INCOME 
     $(".salary-upd-submit").click(function() {
          var elem = $(this);
          $.post("update_salary.php", elem.parent("#salary-upd").serialize(), function(data) {
                elem.next("div").html(data);
          });
    });
```

***PHP***

```
 $uid = $_SESSION['oauth_id'];
   $monthly_income = $_POST['monthly-income'];


 #update Record
       $query = mysql_query("SET `income` (user_id, monthly_income) VALUES ($uid, '$monthly_income')") or die(mysql_error());
```

---

tried to update my PHP as I thought it may be that...

```
  $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `income` SET (user_id, monthly_income) VALUES ($uid, '$monthly_income')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This jug begs for SQL injection. Sanitize your input!

Comment: **Don't pass raw user input into SQL.** Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_` functions, which are being deprecated.

Comment: @DCoder I would welcome the `mysql_` being deprecated, but as far as I can tell, they're not :-(

Comment: @jeroen: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the others will fix your JS-side issues, but the query you are passing to `MySQL` in your script won't parse.

Try using something like this:

```
$sanitized_monthly_income = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['monthly-income']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO income (user_id, monthly_income) VALUES ('$uid', '$sanitized_monthly_income') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE monthly_income = VALUES(monthly_income)");
```

Comment: @Liam: that's very descriptive.

Comment: Sorry, the page doesnt show anything, Nothings inserted into my DB neither, ill try put error reporting on the .php page

Comment: I receive 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_query() in /home/clients/billings/update_salary.php on line 18'

Comment: @Liam: my bad, please try now.

Comment: Thanks @Quassnoi, I now receive 'Notice: Undefined index: monthly_income in /home/liamm.co.uk/public_html/clients/billings/update_salary.php on line 18'

Is this because I've not included the column id in the query?

Comment: thanks @quassnoi, it inserts now, only problem is it adds another row, is this because Im missing the ID Column from the query?

Comment: @Liam: yes, that's because of it. Check your `$uid`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the page-refresh, I would recommend attaching the action to the form submit handler and prevent the default submit event:

```
$("#salary-upd").on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var elem = $(this);
      $.post("update_salary.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            elem.next("div").html(data);
      });
});
```

**Edit:** For older versions of jQuery, the first line would be:

```
 $("#salary-upd").submit(function(event) {
```

About the php:

- Use prepared statements to avoid sql injection problems
- Use error handling to see what's wrong

Comment: I receive 'Unknown system variable 'income''

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".salary-upd-submit").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var elem = $(this);
    $.post("update_salary.php", elem.parent("#salary-upd").serialize(), function (data) {
        elem.next("div").html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you clicking on the button before the dom finishes loading ? I would wrap the functionality in document ready to make sure it executes only after the dom finishes loading.

add preventDefault to prevent the default form submit behaviour. Other wise you may not be able to notice that it is reloaded via ajax because the entire page will be submited.

```
$(function(){
  $(".salary-upd-submit").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //prevent default submit behavior.  
      var elem = $(this);
      $.post("update_salary.php", elem.parent("#salary-upd").serialize(), function(data) {
            elem.next("div").html(data);
      });
  });
});
```